# Cant request javascript variable in code behind always returns ""

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Im trying to request javascript variable and use it in code behind, but it always has the value of ""
Im not sure whats wrong, it should work based on examples I have looked at.
Any help - or different methods to request Js variable to .net webforms (c#) would be very much appreciated, thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetPostbackValues() {
    var myvalue = "abcdefg";
    document.getElementById("hiddenControl1").value = myvalue;
}
</script>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <input id="hiddenControl1" type="hidden" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  OnClientClick="SetPostbackValues()" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</div>

 ....
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    var hiddenValue = hiddenControl1.Value;
    //use value
 }
```

Comment: You need `ClientIdMode`

Answer (score 0):

Its working now I changed the following:

```
<input id="hiddenControl1" type="hidden" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

document.getElementById("<%= hiddenControl1.ClientID %>").value = myvalue;
```